# Uploading data from GoogleColab into GitHub or Kaggle

Tags: github, github-api, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Is there a way to upload data from a local file storage in GoogleColab into GitHub or a Kaggle profile account?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems to be open ended, I'll answer it as best as I could. If you are thinking of a more specific kind of data, do add a concrete example.

One way is to simple use git command line tool.

```
github_repo = example_repo
file_to_sync = 'some_path/some_file'
!git clone https://github.com/user/$github_repo
!cp $file_to_sync $github_repo
!cd $github_repo && git add $file_to_sync && git commit -m "file added"
!cd $github_repo && git push
```